# Referral traffic from googleasdservices.com in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, traffic, remarketing

I am seeing referral traffic (not a great volume) in GA coming from googleadservices.com - I suspect that this is actually traffic coming from paid remarketing ads so why would this be logged as referral and not cpc by GA?
Has anyone else experienced this and found an explanation?

Comment: recheck the URL, is it googleasdservices.com or googleadservices.com as your title has different spelling then your description, provide correct information to get it resolved

Comment: is or were your website running Google Ads or Adsense?

Answer (score 1):

It is spyware as according to [this site](http://www.spyware-techie.com/google-lead-services-removal-guide):

They write:

> When your browsing experience is disrupted by annoying third-party banner and pop-up ads, Google Lead Services could be the one to blame. Although its name may suggest that it has something to do with Google, the truth is that it does not.